# Does RAD6 support JDK6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-6, ibm-rad

Kindly tell me that RAD6 support JDK6? If yes then how can I add the support of JDK6 in RAD6?
I cannot use RAD7 due to my company policy.

Comment: It is unlikely that the [JDT tools](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-preferences-compiler.htm) in RAD6 will support Java versions beyond 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

IBM RAD6 is basically Eclipse, and Eclipse basically supports pretty much any (Sun) JDK you want to run with.

... BUT ...

The current version of the product is RAD8 - RAD6 is over 5 years old.

So if you can afford to, try it.  But there are no guarantees.  And since the product is obsolete, there's little hope for vendor support if you run into problems...

IMHO...

Comment: While Eclipse (and thus probably RAD as well) support any JDK at all, it *does* include a compiler, and if the included compiler doesn't know the desired language level, then using the up-to-date JDK doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question RAD or the eclipse version that it built on will support any JDK that you want to use. The only caveat is the built in JRE plugin might not be the latest Java release. I am assuming you want to use RAD5 IDE (which comes with IBM jdk version 5) instead you want to use JDK 6 from oracle

You can do this by adding JDK this way and use that JDK to compile your java code.

- Window ==>Preferences ==> Java ==> Installed JREs ==> Add
- Click ADD and select the root directory of JDK that you want to use
- Then select the check box besides the JRE to enable RAD to use that JDK